# Proper path to modify villager anger?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I would like to make villagers angry on command. I assume I need to use `/data modify`, but I do not know the proper `<targetPath>`. I have the following so far:

```
execute as @e[type=villager] run data modify entity @s Target set from entity @a[sort=nearest,limit=1] {Gossips:[{Type:"minor_negative",Value:5}]}
```

I also have a potential contender, but this required a manual entry of the "Target", which obviously is not possible

```
execute as @e[type=villager] run data merge entity @s {Gossips:[{Type:"major_positive",Value:20,Target:<>}
```

I had hoped these two could be used in conjunction, to set the gossip then assign the target, but that does not seem to be the case.

Specifically, I would like to do this when their workstation is broken, which I know I can do with level 1 villagers easily (by testing if they drop from 1 to 0) but if anyone has a way of doing that for other levels it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to figure it out myself. Here are the commands I used:

```
execute as @e[type=villager] run data merge entity @s {Gossips:[{Type:"major_positive",Value:20,Target:[I;1,1,1,1]}]}

execute as @e[type=villager] run data modify entity @s Gossips[0].Target set from entity @p UUID
```

Comment: So, I tested and editing the UUID after creating the gossip didn't work + if you already have a gossip of a type from a certain UUID only the biggest one prevails instead of adding up. Also, what about the part of the question on how to detect lost stations? I can post that part if you want (I was still working on the nbt part)

Comment: I can easily do it for level 1 villagers going back to 0, but if you have a way of detecting when any villagers has their workstation broken (specifically the leveled up ones), that would be appreciated

Comment: Did it. What about the nbt part, did it work on your tests?

Comment: All bounties are final and cannot be refunded. You also can't award your own answer. Thus, if you found the other answer helpful, you *can* award it at your discretion.

Comment: He kind of helped with a different issue, but not the initial question I asked. That I had to figure out myself without help. Therefore, if I can not award my answer the bounty, then I need it refunded since I did not get an answer.

Comment: That's a fair choice - its your call! But again, there is no way to refund a bounty.  It's not possible.  You are out 100 reputation unfortunately.  You can read over the [bounty help page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

#### Detecting a broken station

Looking a bit on how villagers work, their data path stores where their station is placed under `Brain.memories."minecraft:job_site".value.pos`. If that is empty, it has none; if that has something, it has a station. We can use the store command to store in a score if they had a station in a previous tick. So we create a score called `HasStation` and set each villager score's to the result of the data. Before that, we check if the villager doesn't have the data **and** has his score set to 1:

```
execute as @e[type=minecraft:villager] unless data entity @s Brain.memories."minecraft:job_site".value.pos if score @s HasStation matches 1 run say I lost my station
execute as @e[type=minecraft:villager] store success score @s HasStation run data get entity @s Brain.memories."minecraft:job_site".value.pos
```

Just modify the `run say ...` to something of your desire.

##### Detecting who broke it

You can also attach the station breaking to a player, but that is a bit more hard-coded. You simply create a scoreboard for each minecraft.custom.break.[station_block] and, whenever that goes to 1, send it to a single scoreboard (so instead of having 100 scoreboards for each block, you have a single one).

Then, when the first command of the two runs, there will be a player which score is above 0. Simply target the closest to for its UUID and attach it to the Target of the Gossip. Something like:

```
execute as @e[type=minecraft:villager] unless data entity @s Brain.memories."minecraft:job_site".value.pos if score @s HasStation matches 1 run data merge entity @s {Gossips:[{Type:"major_negative",Value:20,Target:[I;1,1,1,1]}]}
execute as @e[type=minecraft:villager] unless data entity @s Brain.memories."minecraft:job_site".value.pos if score @s HasStation matches 1 run data modify entity @s Gossips[0].Target set from entity @p[scores={destroyedStation=1..}] UUID
execute as @e[type=minecraft:villager] unless data entity @s Brain.memories."minecraft:job_site".value.pos if score @s HasStation matches 1 run scoreboard players remove @p[scores={destroyedStation=1..}] destroyedStation 1
execute as @e[type=minecraft:villager] store success score @s HasStation run data get entity @s Brain.memories."minecraft:job_site".value.pos
```

Since all three starting lines have the same if statement, it would be wise to create a function for it.

Comment: Ill just assume villagers are dumb and get angry at the nearest player even if there are potentially more than one, but thanks for the first part